# Noclass def found error in kafa TestProducer example

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to execute the example at :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example

I built the project using maven and built was successful. But while executing the jar I am getting following error.

```
[root@sandbox target]# java -cp kafka_code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.kafka.TestProducer 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/producer/ProducerConfig
        at com.kafka.TestProducer.main(TestProducer.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.producer.ProducerConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 1 more
```

However my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka_code</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>kafka_code</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.1.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
       <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
       <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
       <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     </exclusion>
     <exclusion>
       <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
       <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ja-fra.zk-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkconfig</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The kafka_code-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is not built along with the dependencies. There are two ways you can go about doing it. Either add all dependencies into a library folder and provide it as your class-path input at runtime or get all the dependent classes into one single package. You can use assembly plugin to build all dependency into one. Add the assembly plugin dependency to your build phase in your pom.xml. Build the jar use mvn assembly:single. This will create a jar-with-dependencies, which you can use to run you kafka producer.

```
      <build>
           <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
```